# Javascript engine fails while executing this regex if given long strings to test

Tags: javascript, regex

This regex is written to disallow the urls starting with any url scheme and slashes(forward slash, backward slash) but will allow urls like "domain.tld" which are not starting with any url scheme or slashes. It should also allow the strings which are not url("some random input").

```
^(?!://)((?!//))(?!(.*?)*://)(?!:\\\\)(?!:/\\\\/\\\\)(?!(.*?)*:/\\\\/\\\\)(?!/\\\\/\\\\)(?!\\\\)(?!(.*?)*:\\\\)(?!www.)(?!(.*?)*.www.).*$
```

This regex works fine in java but in javscript, it is failing for longer strings.

Example: It works fine for `"hey. hey hey hey hey"` but starts taking time with `"hey. hey hey hey hey "` and hangs after `"hey. hey hey hey hey hey hey"`

Following are the cases which should be tested against the regex:

```
String                  | Expected result
__________________________________________
http://www.google.com   | False
HTTP://WWW.google.com   | False
adasd://www.google.com  | False
ftp://www.google.com    | False
mailto://www.google.com | False
//www.google.com        | False
://www.google.com       | False
www.google.com          | False
WWW.google.com          | False
test .http://google.com | False
skksdwww.google.com     | False
wWW.google.com          | False
://google.com           | False
.www.google.com         | False
as;;; .wwW.google.com   | False
as.wwW.google.com       | False
= #$@%@#.www.google.com | False
http:/\\/\\google.com   | False
:/\\/\\google.com       | False
http://gogle.com        | False
gogle.com //google.com  | False
google.com              | true
some random input       | true
```

What could be the problem in it?

UPDATE: I have updated the regex as per Wiktor Stribiżew's comment and it works fine.

Comment: See  `(.*?)*` - this is a disastrous subpattern in larger patterns. Use a mere `(.*?)`. Also, if you need to match a literal dot, escape it. See [`^(?!://)((?!//))(?!(.*?)://)(?!:\\\\)(?!:/\\\\/\\\\)(?!(.*?):/\\\\/\\\\)(?!/\\\\/\\\\)(?!\\\\)(?!(.*?):\\\\)(?!www\.)(?!(.*?)\.www\.).*$`](https://regex101.com/r/mH6hK7/1).

Comment: I have to write it because I want to look for every possible url schemes(custom as well)

Comment: You do not have to say: match something unlimited number of times unlimited number of times. If you multiply infinity with infinity, what will you get?

Comment: woah!! Thanks a TON!! works.. :) If you could write it as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Well, I only showed where the issue is, but the pattern requires revamping for sure.

Comment: Out of curiosity, there's a lot of testing for things that don't even _look_ like urls, or the urls are buried in some other part of the string. And also the whole `/\\/\\` thing. What's all that about?

Comment: Yeah, that looks suspicious. Also, your fixed regex [matches some unwanted strings](https://regex101.com/r/mH6hK7/2). Even [if you do not escape the dots](https://regex101.com/r/mH6hK7/4).

Comment: Have a look at this video about catastrophic backtracking. It basically boils down to the Regex engine having too many options to look through. https://vimeo.com/112065252

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the one highlighted ones are fine as confirmed by the tester and the PM!! :|

Comment: Then please update the test cases. But please "think twice then cut". Too many edits in the requirements are frowned upon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `(.*?)*` subpattern is disastrous inside larger patterns. The nested `*` quantifiers (lazy inside and greedy outside) allow the regex engine to check a huge amount of substring variations before a failure occurs with a string that should not be matched.

**Always test your patterns against strings that should not match**.

Also, if you need to match a literal dot, escape it.

Here is your fixed and contracted regex:

```
^
  (?!.*?:?//)
  (?!:(?:/\\\\/)?\\\\)
  (?!(?:.*?:)?(?:/\\\\/)?\\\\)
  (?!(?:.*?\.)?www\.)
 .*
$
```

Or a one-liner:

```
^(?!.*?:?//)(?!:(?:/\\\\/)?\\\\)(?!(?:.*?:)?(?:/\\\\/)?\\\\)(?!(?:.*?\.)?www\.).*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mH6hK7/7)

Answer (score 1):

I didn't examine the whole thing (wow, that's a lot of slashes!) but you could greatly simplify the regex, I'm guessing. Just going from your post, maybe this would work for you:

`/^(?!.*(?:www\.|\/\/|\/\\\\\/\\\\))/i`

Should test negative for any protocol, including an empty one, including `file:` urls. Let me know if I've missed anything the regex needs to test for.

UPDATE: Now passes all tests.

Comment: Na! doesnt work.. regEx.test("abc") // should return true, regEx.test("abc.com") // should return true

Comment: Do you mean "abc" should return false? They both return `true` for me.

Comment: ohh.. yeah. it works fine for both "abc" and "abc.com". checked with regex literal and wasn't working in that. But it doesn't solve every possible case. I will update my question with cases.